# How to invoke Job/Task in Azure Databricks from Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

I need to develop a event driven pipeline which should get trigger on file arrival in ADLS2 i.e. ABFS. On file arrival I need to trigger 4 subsequent Spark jobs on Azure Databricks cluster.
For orchestrating the Spark Jobs I can use Databricks jobs as an option so that jobs could get triggered in a pipeline.
But the first job should get triggered only after the file arrival.

I am currently exploring ways to achieve this but need expert advice to design this in a best possible manner w.r.t cost.

One solution could be to use Azure Data Factory for orchestrating the entire flow based on Storage Event Trigger component but going for ADF just because of event based trigger don't look feasible to me as the rest part of the application i.e. Spark jobs can be pipelined from Databricks Job feature. 
Also, in terms of cost ADF can be expensive.
 Another solution could be to use Azure Functions Blob Trigger to know the file arrival but I am not able to understand how can I trigger Azure Databricks jobs from Azure Functions. As going with Functions can be cost effective as the function would not be running/active until the file has arrived.

Note:There can be multiple files arriving in an hour. No fixed duration on file arrival.

Also, trigger file is different than data files. i.e. On arrival of trigger files, Spark pipeline would consume actual data files. 
Data files and Trigger files have different extensions and both are arriving in ABFS.

Comment: does this answers your question? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72664052/calling-databricks-python-notebook-in-azure-function/72667368?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C0.0000#72667368

Comment: This really is too broad, and falls under recommendations (off-topic). I'm not sure I understand the issue with data factory (as data factory can indeed orchestrate different databricks jobs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your worry about ADF cost is misplaced.  The Pipelines are extremely cheap.  The activities that actually move data and use CPU are where most of the cost is.  For instance Data Flows are run on managed Spark clusters, which is reflected in the pricing.  See [Data Factory Pricing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/pricing-concepts).  Using a Pipeline to orchestrate Databricks jobs is a common, simple, and (at least for ADF) very inexpensive.

If you want to kick off a Databricks job from an Azure Function, there's an [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/2.0/jobs).  Also check out the [Databricks Autoloader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/auto-loader/), but running your Databricks cluster continuously can be expensive.